# using a function that returns a function with params

Tags: redux, flutter, dart

I'm new to `dart flutter` and `redux`

what i'm doing is saving data to the store for when i move to next screen

this is the call for the save itself in the converter

```
Function saveCurrent(Store<AppState> store) {
    return (FlightsListItemViewModel currentFlight) => 
    store.dispatch(SaveCurrentFlight(currentFlight : currentFlight));
}
```

but my question is how do i call it ? I used :

```
saveCurrentViewModel: saveCurrent(store)
```

but it crashed as

> Object.noSuchMethod

maybe because I need to pass him the currentFlight data , how do I do that ?

and also is the redux logic right for me ? putting the function in the selector and calling it from the selector ?

Thanks a lot to the helpers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```dart
saveCurrent(store)(currentFlight);
```

Here's a simple example that I tested in Dartpad:

```dart
Function fun(int a) {
  return (b) => print("$a, $b");
}

void main() {
  fun(3)(4); 
}
```